# Getting error like "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Tags: laravel-5

I want to edit the post so gone through the edit route process but it's showing error like

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

I tried in `edit.blade.php` `method="post"` and also "POST" and in `route.php` changed `Route::POST` to `Route::Post/Put`

In `edit.blade.php`

```
<form class="form"action="{{route('Staff.update')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
```

and in `web.php`

```
Route::get('/Staff/edit/{id}',[
    'uses'=>'StaffController@edit',
    'as'=>'staff.edit'
]);

Route::Post('/Staff/update/{id}',[
    'uses'=>'Staffcontroller@update',
    'as'=>'Staff.update'
]);
```

Comment: Does your form really have `class="form"action=...`, without a space, or is that just a typo here?  Also, How is your form submitted?  Also, the `Staff.update` route in your form needs an `id` - [the Laravel docs show how to do that](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes). Also, probably not important, but [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing) do not use mixed-case route verbs like you have (`Post`), only lower case (`post`), so at least until you've solved your issue I'd do the same.

Comment: Thank you, here is my code  <form class="form"  action="{{route('Staff.update')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {{csrf_field()}} and in

Comment: If your code is not what you have shown in the question, edit the question and update.  Also, see all the other points in my last comment.

Comment: Sorry, I was out of city so couldn't attend or online..this is my route 
Route::get('/Staff/edit/{id}',[

    'uses'=>'StaffController@edit',
    'as'=>'Staff.edit'

]);
Route::post('/Staff/update/{id}',[

    'uses'=>'StaffController@update',
    'as'=>'Staff.update'

]);

Comment: and this is   <form class="form" action="{{route('Staff.update',['id'=>$staff->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {{csrf_field()}}  code for form and there is space in between